# Beautiful Soup find() returns None?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the HTML on this [website](https://trashnothing.com/washington-dc-freecycle?page=1).

I would like to get the text from all these `span` elements with `class = "post-subject"`

Examples:

```
<span class="post-subject">Set of 20 moving boxes (20009 or 20011)</span>

<span class="post-subject">Firestick/Old xbox games</span>
```

When I run my code below, `soup.find()` returns `None`. I'm not sure what's going on?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://trashnothing.com/washington-dc-freecycle?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

soup.find('span', {'class': 'post-subject'})
```

Comment: If you run `document.querySelector('.post-subject')` on that page, that will also return none. Where do you see elements with a class of `post-subject`? Do you have to run a search or interact with the page first? If so, you'll need to do that before calling BeautifulSoup...

Comment: The page needs a login. Check out `mechanize` or `Selenium` for ways to access webpages a little more interactively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help you get started the following should load the page you will need to get the correct [gecko driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and then can implement with Selenium. I do not see a class: post-subject on that page you linked, but you can automate button clicks for the login as :

```
availbutton = driver.find_element_by_id('buttonAvailability_1')
availbutton.click()
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://trashnothing.com/washington-dc-freecycle?page=1')

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print(soup.find('span', {'class': 'post-subject'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Just changed the `html.parser` to `html5lib` and boom. It was working then. Also its a good practice to use `soup.find_all()` instead of `soup.find()` as the function return more than one object

Comment: Had the same issue. Thank you for your answer. It worked :)